# Change TextView size using a SeekBar

Tags: android, seekbar, text-size

It works well when I try to Change  text size in (EditText) by putting a constant value in code <<<<

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    EditText Text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    SeekBar f = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

    Text.setTextSize(55);

    Text.setText("Hello");



}
```

But I Can't get it to work by using SeekBar:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    EditText Text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    SeekBar f = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

    Text.setTextSize((float)f.getProgress());

    Text.setText("Hello");



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the text size using this listener:

```
f.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       

    @Override       
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }       

    @Override       
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }       

    @Override       
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {     
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

        Text.setTextSize(progress);

    }
```

Comment: If works for you, mark it as best answer. 

It didn't work with your code because you only set it once. If you want to listen to the Seekbar changes you have to add a listener. In this case "setOnSeekBarChangeListener"